# Linux tc filter add - errors RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported

Tags: filter, tc, netfilter, traffic-shaping

I'm working on the network simulation to create some traffic on specific ports , and trying to inject the network delay. I'm using the linux tc utility to do this operations. So i'm new to the tc command , help will be much appreciated.

I tried to add filter using the tc filter command and it gave the "RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
We have an error talking to the kernel"

Below are the commands i ran in particular order,

1. `sudo /sbin/tc qdisc show`

   ```
    qdisc mq 0: dev eth0 root 
    qdisc pfifo_fast 0: dev eth0 parent :1 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   ```
2. Then I added the delay using the below command,

   `sudo /sbin/tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent :1 netem delay 100ms`
3. Now i can see and list the delay

   `sudo /sbin/tc qdisc show`

   ```
    `qdisc mq 0: dev eth0 root `
    `qdisc netem 8006: dev eth0 parent :1 limit 1000 delay 100.0ms`
   ```
4. Next i ran the below command to add the filter to the port 7000

   `sudo /sbin/tc filter add dev eth0 parent :1 protocol ip u32 match ip sport 7000 0xffff flowid 1:2`

   `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported We have an error talking to the kernel`
5. Can you please help me in how to add the filter to match the port?
6. Is there a way not to match , like is there a way to exclude the specfic ports in the filter command

Thanks

Comment: You really must read this first (it's old, but still useful): https://lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.classful.html (that's chapter 9.5, but the whole of chapter 9 is needed too).